# Writing regular expression to check mandatory as well as optional strings in a given input

Tags: java, regex

I have the following string pattern

```
aB_12345_topicName_A15.jpg
```

where `topicName` is mandatory part and it can be any string and remaining all optional.

---

Example valid inputs are:

```
aB_SportsTopic.png
12345_topicName.jpg
Environment.jpg
topicName_A15.jpg
topicName_2B5.jpg
aB_12345_topicName.jpg
```

How to write a regular expression in java to validate user input accordingly?
I have written like this so far

```
^[a-z A-Z]_?\_[a-z A-Z]*_\[[0-9]*\][a-z A-Z]*_[a-z A-Z 0-9]*_[a-z A-Z 0-9]{3}\.[a-z A-Z]*
```

How to write regular expression for it in java?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you only whant to check if the string contains `topicName`? Can you descript the logic you need?

Comment: how `aB_SportsTopic.png` is valid?

Comment: @SpringLearner topicName=SportsTopic and _12345, _A15 are optional

Answer (score 0):

Here is the regExp you search:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*topicName[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$
```

**Edited.** You can do it also if topicName is any String. Just concatenate the first part, the topicName and the last part of regExp.

```
public String myRegExp(String topicName) {
    return "^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*" + topicName + "[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$";
}
```

and call it as you like most, for example:

```
String regExp1 = myRegExp("pippo");
String regExp2 = myRegExp("topicName");
String regExp3 = myRegExp("otherTopic");
```

Comment: topicName can be any string but it should be in place

Answer (score 0):

If you want topicName to be in place there is regular expression:

```
    ^[A-Za-z0-9_]*[A-Za-z0-9]+[A-Za-z0-9_]*(.[a-z]*)$
```

If you need something else [check this link](http://regexpal.com/). You can write regExp and check it there.